# I am getting bruteforce attack from locvangxuanfb2019.com

Tags: wordpress, brute-force-attacks

In my wordpress website, I am getting bruteforce login attempts from locvangxuanfb2019.com and hopquavn2019.com

When I try to ping locvangxuanfb2019.com and hopquavn2019.com I get response from localhost. Even on my computer.

I have never seen such kind of attacks yet. Can anybody explain what is this and how can I prevent such issues.